# Automating reboot of servers

Tags: hardware, datacenter, console

We have 1,000 servers having different manufacturer and a mix of Solaris and Linux. They go down frequently and we end up rebooting by logging in to the Integrated Lights Out Manager (ILOM).

I want to automate this by having a script which reboots a host once it goes non-pingable.

So is a shell/Perl script to get into the ILOM and console of a server possible?

What can be my approach?

Comment: "They go down frequently..." Have you considered solving *this* problem first?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at the [expect](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=linux%20expect) utility. It can use used to automate scripts where input is required.

Personally, I'd be trying to understand why the systems crash so frequently that this is needed and solving the real problem.

Comment: ILO from HP can accept a private key, this might allow `ssh ilo reboot`